# php + mysql сравнение

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт должен получить из таблицы в MySQL 2 значения и сравнить их, при получение значения "pass" на страниц выдает "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' pass = '1234'' at line 1". Если не передавать значение "pass", то ошибки нету.

```
 $log = mysql_query("SELECT email, pass FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email'])."', pass = $pass");

$sql = ($log) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT email, pass FROM users WHERE email=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email'])." AND pass = $pass"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!